# cl.exe /I \include gets ignored

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, linker, cl, cl.exe

I am trying to compile SDL2 program using cl.exe and vscode tasks.
For some reason /I flag gets ignored completely by cl.exe from the cli.
The task is specified as:

```
    {
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "cppbuild",
      "label": "C/C++: cl.exe build active file",
      "command": "cl.exe",
      "args": [
        "/Zi",
        "/EHsc",
        "/nologo",
        "/Fe:",
        "${workspaceFolder}\\build\\hello.exe",
        "${workspaceFolder}\\src\\*.cpp",
        "/I C:\\Users\\stackoverflow\\path\\to\\include\\folder\\include\\",
        "/link C:\\Users\\stackoverflow\\path\\to\\include\\folder\\lib\\x86\\SDL2main.lib C:\\Users\\stackoverflow\\path\\to\\include\\folder\\lib\\x86\\SDL2.lib"
      ],
      "problemMatcher": ["$msCompile"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    }
  ],
  "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

And for some reason it only finds the header files if I specify the whole path in the code like:

```
#include <C:\Users\stackoverflow\path\to\include\folder\include\SDL2\SDL.h>
```

But it gives fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: <...> No such file or directory
when I use:

```
#include <SDL2\SDL.h>
```

Official docs suggest that it should work: [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/i-additional-include-directories?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-160)

Same problem occurs when using the developer cli by visual studio.
What am I missing here?

UPDATE:

It works when I remove the whitespace before /I like so:

```
"/IC:\\Users\\stackoverflow\\path\\to\\include\\folder\\include",
"/linkC:\\Users\\stackoverflow\\path\\to\\include\\folder\\lib\\x86\\SDL2main.lib C:\\Users\\stackoverflow\\path\\to\\include\\folder\\lib\\x86\\SDL2.lib"
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the trailing backslash(es) from the include path? The example given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/i-additional-include-directories?view=msvc-160) doesn't have any.

Comment: Same error, but I believe escaping \ should be used because of how tasks json is specified. [msvc-vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc)

Comment: You tried with `"/I C:\\Users\\stackoverflow\\path\\to\\include\\folder\\include",`?

Comment: Figured that I have to remove the whitespace before the string. `/IC:\\path ...`. I will update the question. Weird behaviour.